# Are $n$-dimension cubes $C^k$ manifolds with boundaries?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

I had a look at this very helpful post:

[What does it mean to say a boundary is $C^k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150747/what-does-it-mean-to-say-a-boundary-is-ck)

From what I can understand higher dimension cubes do not fall in this category, because there is no way we can find a homeomorphism which can deal with the corners.

However, I am a little confused about if we take an interval $[a,b]$, it would appear to me that this is a manifold with $C^\infty$ boundary.

Please can someone confirm this?

The reason I ask this is because Kondrachov embedding theorem requires the domain of the PDE to be a **compact manifold with $C^1$ boundary**.

Am I close to think the theorem would apply to a sphere or an interval (1 dimension "cube") but does not hold on a cube in general?

Comment: For the Kondrachov embedding theorem, I think Lipschitzness (Lipschitzity?) of domain is enough, and I believe that hypercubes have this property.

Comment: @AlexS can you please provide me with a reference. My source is Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. My source is also Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem), but here it says Lipschitz is sufficient, while the Soboloev Embedding Theorem page says differentiability. A quick search of other articles seems to confirm this, but nowhere do I see an argument that Lipschitz is not enough. It seems that in the proof of the Kondrachov Theorem, differentiability is required in the use of the uniformly smooth approximation lemma, whose proof relies heavily on this fact. So either Wikipedia is wrong, or there is another proof.

Comment: @AlexS can you just confirm for me that my understanding for boundary is correct.

Comment: You are correct. The closed interval has $C^\infty$ boundary, while every other finite dimensional cube has non-differentiable points.

Comment: Higher dimensional cubes do not have a smooth boundary, but there is a natural category of "manifolds with corners": http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.3518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the question posed: yes, an interval is a domain with $C^\infty$ boundary. A definition of $C^k$ smooth boundary which makes this clear is: every boundary point has a neighborhood $U$ such that $\Omega\cap U$ is of the form $\{x: \phi(x)<0\}$ where $\phi$ is $C^k$ smooth in $U$ and has nonvanishing gradient there.

By the implicit function theorem the above is equivalent to the graph definition. But in the case $n=1$ it's easier to interpret the "implicit" definition: just take $\phi(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$ for the interval $(a,b)$.

In higher dimensions, cubes are Lipschitz domains, but not smooth. The implicit definition makes it clear: at an edge, $\nabla \phi$ would have to be orthogonal to both faces meeting there.

And yes, Lipschitz boundary is enough for the Sobolev embedding and for  the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem.